# Ajustar layout a diferentes tipos de resolução

Tags: android

Estou criando minha aplicação e para teste estava usando o dispositivo virtual Pixel XL que tem a resolução 1440x2560, porém hoje fui testar a aplicação em outro dispositivo (Nexus - 720X1280) e para minha surpresa o layout não se reajustou. Segue abaixo um comparativo, a direita é o Pixel XL e a esquerda o Nexus:

Como faço para o layout se auto dimensionar de acordo com a resolução dos dispositivos? Criei uma variante do diretório layout para os tamanhos large e normal, porém ficou meio confuso pra mim já que o large engloba vários dispositivos com várias resoluções, a mesma coisa o normal. O problema estaria no próprio layout? Também não saberia como criar um layout totalmente responsivo. Segue o XML do layout em questão:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#fcfcfc"
android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circulo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_receita_branco1"
                android:padding="13dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_receita"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvReceita"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_receita_desc"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circulo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pedidos_branco"
                android:padding="13dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_pedidos"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPedidos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_pedidos_desc"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circulo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_clientes_branco"
                android:padding="13dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_clientes"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvClientes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_clientes_desc"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circulo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_estoque_branco"
                android:padding="13dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_estoque"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEstoque"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_estoque_desc"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circulo"
                android:padding="13dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_funcionarios_branco" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_funcionarios"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFuncionarios"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="37dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"

                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="@string/dashboard_funcionarios_desc"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um método é você criar arquivos de layout para cada tipo de resolução. 
por exemplo:
activity_main-hdpi

activity_main-xhdpi

ou

activity_main-sw320

activity_main-sw600

activity_main-sw1024

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Outra forma é, utilizar porcentagens para criar o tamanho dos cards.

```
android:layout_width="160dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight=".25"
```

Esse objeto terá 25% do tamanho do pai.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout

Depende muito do projeto há outros approches, porém, acho esses dois os melhores.

Comment: Estava vendo sobre essas pastas layout-sw320, layout-sw600... Mas pra mim funcionou mesmo com layout-sw320-mdpi, layout-sw320-hdpi, layout-sw320-xhdpi... Pois deixa muito mais específico os layouts. Sobre a  porcentagem eu não sabia, vou dar uma olhada.